# async.each doesn't run callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-request, node-async

I'm trying to do something after push data from reddit api to array, but callback function doesn't work at all. As you see the code, It's supposed to print `Callback function works!` but It doesn't. Is there any ideas about this?

```
let optForReddit = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://www.reddit.com/domain/eroshare.com/new.json',
  json: true
}

  rp(optForReddit)
    .then(function(redditJSON) {
      let posts = redditJSON.data.children;
      let len = posts.length;
      let eroJson = [];
      async.each(posts, function(item, callback) {
          if (isVideo(item.data.url)) {
            eroJson.push(getAlbumId(item.data.url));
          }
      },    
      function(err) {
          console.log("Callback function works");
          if(err) console.log(err);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async.each(posts, function(item, callback) {
      if (isVideo(item.data.url)) {
        eroJson.push(getAlbumId(item.data.url));
      }
      callback();  // this callback is for informing that i am done processing one item in array.
  },    
  function(err) {
      //this function will be invoked when the callback() in the above body was called maximum time(e.g posts.length times)
      console.log("Callback function works");
      if(err) console.log(err);
  });
```

this is because you are not calling callback function each time. callback when called tells the async function that i am done with the current execution and call next iteraion. You never called the callback().

Comment: but I want to call the callback function after the each loop is done. how can I do?

Comment: like you want to execute loop serially? so it executes in order?

Comment: yes! so the callback function can run after everything is done.

Comment: I solved the problem! I just had to use `eachSeries` not `each`. Thank you for help anyways!

Comment: I have a question, eachSeries in waterfall would work or not?

Comment: `async.eachSeries` only called once. do you have any idea about it? my code is here http://pastebin.com/uK45fRzT. even though the length of posts is 25.

Comment: this is baecause you are still not calling the callback function. if you are not calling the callback function how would async know that one iteration is done?

Comment: oh my god i was being so dumb lol Thank you so much! Have a nice weekend though its sunday!

Comment: look at my answer above. see where i am calling callback. you are doing same with the async.eachSeries

Comment: I did! :) Thank you